# Slick slider console error

Tags: javascript, console, typeerror, slick.js

I am currently getting this console error from slick slider:

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.$list.prop is not a function
```

I am using this slider on three different sites -all implemented the same exact way. It was working on one of the sites until one day it just went blank. The error I get is on `slick.min.js` Has anyone else run into this problem? Does anyone know what this error is? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Here's a dev site that has the issue: http://dev.semananews.beta.lionheartdms.com/ With @Radiance suggestion, I loaded slick.min.js at the end and it now displays the image but the slider doesn't work still. I now get this console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.type is not a function
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Duniyadnd Post updated with shared site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have added the external js files correctly. According to me the error is occurring because the compiler is not able to find the function which you are using

Comment: I have the same error with the slick.min.js from the cdn (http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js). The code is executed because slick adds the correct classes.

Comment: Hey thank you! This worked. I had to load my js files in my body at the end

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your jQuery version? Slick requires jQuery 1.7 to function properly. (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#dependencies)

Comment: I originally had 1.11.1 loaded -that should work right? I tested and loaded in 1.7 and it still didn't work ...